# WordPress Page Set CPT as Parent

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I would like to try and develop a new website in which the permalink structure will not be following WP's regular structure. What I would like to achieve is the following:

```
index/                          {homepage}
index/cpt-slug-1/               {custom post type cpt-1}
index/cpt-slug-1/page-slug-1    {page with parent cpt-1}
index/cpt-slug-1/page-slug-2    {page with parent cpt-1}
index/cpt-slug-2/               {custom post type cpt-2}
index/cpt-slug-2/page-slug-1    {page with parent cpt-2}
index/cpt-slug-2/page-slug-2    {page with parent cpt-2}
```

One solution I thought of would be to link a CPT to a Page, and based on the template, I would fetch the CPT information and insert it into the page. In theory, this way, the CPT will only be used for metadata. The only drawback with this is that I believe it would not be a clean approach and not optimal when it comes to performance.

I've been researching; however, I cannot find anything on the subject. The closest I got was to set a parent page to a CPT. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you've provided isn't different than what WP already does. Are you trying to have a default WP page post type as a child URL under a CPT permalink? If that's the case, why?

Comment: Yes that's what I'm after. I have some metadata that is being associated with the CPT, and not with the page, and I would like to differentiate the two.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be the correct approach. Can you edit your question to include why (the meta data) and what that actual data is? This may be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)